# Documents are not found in Lucene

Tags: java, search, indexing, lucene, full-text-indexing

I am indexing documents over lucene, the indexes ares created, but when do realize a search, get 0 hits.

I don't know where are the error is in indexing or searching.

**Indexing**

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("C:\\indexes\\teste"));
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);

Document document = new Document();
document.add(new StringField("id", "1", Store.YES));
document.add(new StringField("name", "Pedro Henriques", Store.YES));
document.add(new StringField("displayName", "Pedro Rosa", Store.YES));
document.add(new StringField("segment", "segment xpto", Store.YES));

indexWriter.addDocument(document);
indexWriter.commit();
indexWriter.close();

directory.close();
```

**Search**

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("C:\\indexes\\teste"));
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("", analyzer);
Query query = parser.parse("name:Henriques");
log.info("Consulta analisada-> " + query);

TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 100);
for (ScoreDoc sd : docs.scoreDocs) {
    Document doc = searcher.doc(sd.doc);
    log.info(doc.toString());
}
```

**docs.scoreDocs** is empty.

**My Lucene dependencies are**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

My Java version is 11.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field '**name**' cannot be of type StringField, because fields of this type cannot have spaces, special characters or uppercase letters.

In this case the **TextField** type is used.

```
document.add(new TextField("name", "Pedro Henriques", Store.YES));
```